# WFS layer not displayed on the map

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-6

I use openlayers 6.
I have an issue with displaying a layer on the map.
I load the layer as XML in GML format and try to display, but the layer doesn't show on the map.

Here is the vector definition:

```
function createLayer(layer, strategy, extent, projection) {

    if (!strategy) strategy = allStrategy;
    let vsource = createSourceLayer(strategy, layer, extent, projection);
    var vector = new VectorLayer({
        source: vsource,
        visible: true,
        style: new Style({
            image: new Icon({
                src: '/images/icon-alert-blue.png',
                size: [30, 30],
            })
        })
    });
    return vector;
}
```

Here is the vector source definition:

```
function createSourceLayer(strategy, layer, extent, projection) {

    let url = "url resources";
    let vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        format: new WFS({
            gmlFormat: new GML({
                featureType: "WW_MONITOR",
                featureNS: "http://www.opengis.net/wfs",
                srsName: "EPSG:2039"
            })
        }),
        loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) { 
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    vectorSource.addFeatures(
                        vectorSource.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText, {
                            dataProjection: projection,
                            extent: [195380.430213, 739554.42288, 207900.538587, 750611.382494]
                        })
                    );
                } else {
                    console.log("loader fail");
                }
            },
            xhr.send();
        },
        strategy: strategy
    });

    return vectorSource;
}
```

Here is the map definition:

```
    map = new Map({
        layers: [baseLayer,layer],
        view: view,
        target: 'map',
    });
```

Here is view definition:

```
    view = new View({
        extent: [195380.430213, 739554.42288, 207900.538587, 750611.382494],
        maxResolution: 80000,
        center: [201640.48440000002, 745082.902687],
        projection: israeliTM,
        zoom: 0
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is example of single featuere in GML that I get from server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/gml http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns216630453="http://fdo.osgeo.org/schemas/feature/ns216630453"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <!-- Feature 1 -->
    <gml:featureMember>
        <ns216630453:WW_MONITOR>
            <ns216630453:FeatId>1</ns216630453:FeatId>
            <ns216630453:Name>Donald garage</ns216630453:Name>
            <ns216630453:Street>Dundas str </ns216630453:Street>
            <ns216630453:Building>128</ns216630453:Building>
            <ns216630453:StreetCode>354</ns216630453:StreetCode>
            <ns216630453:FK_Category>11</ns216630453:FK_Category>
            <ns216630453:WaterUsing>27</ns216630453:WaterUsing>
            <ns216630453:Exceptions>0</ns216630453:Exceptions>
            <ns216630453:Geometry>
                <gml:Point>
                    <gml:coordinates>199480.000000,747711.000000</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:Point>
            </ns216630453:Geometry>
        </ns216630453:WW_MONITOR>
    </gml:featureMember>
    <!-- Feature 2 -->
    .
    .
    .
    </wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

And here how it looks after parsing:

```
0: Feature
    dispatching_: {}
        disposed_: false
    geometryChangeKey_: null
    geometryName_: "geometry"
    id_: undefined
    listeners_: {change: geometry: Array(1)}
    ol_uid: "130"
    pendingRemovals_: {}
    revision_: 0
    styleFunction_: undefined
    style_: null
    target_: undefined
    values_:
        Building: "128"
        Exceptions: "0"
        FK_Category: "11"
        FeatId: "1"
        Geometry:
            Point:
                coordinates: "199480.000000,747711.000000"
            __proto__: Object
        __proto__: Object
        Name: "Donald garage"
        Street: "Dundas str"
        StreetCode: "354"
        WaterUsing: "27"
    __proto__: Object
__proto__: BaseObject
```

The projection that I use in vector layer is the same projection that I use in view.
Here the defenition of the projection:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:2039", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.73439361111111 +lon_0=35.20451694444445 +k=1.0000067 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-48,55,52,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
register(proj4);

let israeliTM = getProjection('EPSG:2039');
```

Any idea why the map doesn't show?

Comment: It is difficult to know without access to your data if it is being parsed, for example it might not be compatible with "Simple Features" requirement, or if it is loaded but displayed in the wrong place - projection passed to the loader is the view projection so you need `featureProjection: projection` (in your case it is the same as dataProjection).  You only need extent for pixel based vector tile, but specifying it should not be a problem.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for post. I added additional information about my problem.please see update.

Comment: You have WFS 1.0.0 with GML 2.1.2 so you need to replace `new GML({` with `new GML2({`

Comment: @Mike, thanks it worked. I will accept it as answer if u post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source is WFS 1.0.0 which uses GML 2.1.2

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/gml http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd"
```

So the parser format must be specified as GML2

```
    format: new WFS({
        gmlFormat: new GML2({
            featureType: "WW_MONITOR",
            featureNS: "http://www.opengis.net/wfs",
            srsName: "EPSG:2039"
        })
    }),
```